# ColdFusion Maximum number of simultaneous Web Service Requests

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-administrator

In the ColdFusion Administrator:
Server Settings > Request Tuning

It includes the following Request Limits:
Maximum number of simultaneous Template requests
Maximum number of simultaneous Web Service requests

In the Enterprise Edition both limits can be set.
In the Standard Edition only the Template requests can be set.

My question is, in the Standard Edition, what's the maximum number of simultaneous Web Service requests I can make?
Is it the same as the value set in the Maximum number of simultaneous Template requests?
Or is there an invisible default? And if there is a default, what is it?

Comment: The default setting is 5

Comment: So does that mean, if I increase the "Maximum number of simultaneous Template requests", in the Standard Edition, the "Maximum number of simultaneous Web Service requests" will always remain 5?

Comment: Yes. The maximum number is 5, otherwise the ability to change this value, like in the Enterprise version, would have been added. I guess it is just part of the Standard Edition's reduced functionality.

Comment: It's a shame this is not reflected in the interface. In Standard, it just has a blank, disabled box. It would be better to populate the field. Charles, if you turn your comment into answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on this setting either.  Is there something in the official Adobe docs that states a limit of 5, or just going off personal experience?

Comment: I find it strange that the page for the Standard Edition does not display any value for that setting. If there is a limit of 5, it should display that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting is 5.

This means that the maximum number is 5, otherwise the ability to change this value, like in the Enterprise version, would have been added. I guess it is just part of the Standard Edition's reduced functionality.